# Visual Studio crashes when I add a .settings file in a C++ Windows form application

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, crash, settings.settings

I'm trying to add a .settings file in a windows form application by adding a (whatever) file in the project and have it named smthng.settings. Right after it is created, it crashes (if I look into the project's directory the file is there, but it's not "in" the project). Am I doing it wrong or could it be that the problem lies elsewhere?

Edit: It seems that it's the settings designer that crashes.

Partially Solved:If I add a `(whatever).config` file, then rename it to .settings and change it's file type to C/C++ Code (don't ask how I figured this out..) then I can add to it settings, but if I do add something that has any connection to the form then automatically a `(whatever).config` with thew same name spawns (which is identical to the `(whatever).setting` even if change one of them) and at the `stdafx.cpp` a `#include '(whatever).h'` appears, which is a problem, because there is not such a header. (if I erase it or just create a blank `(whatever).h` it doesn't work. Apparently I have to somehow connect all the data in the `(w/e).settings` to `(w/e).h` as well or maybe something else) Anyone had this problem before? Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If it crashes, then regarding of what else you may be doing wrong, it's a bug - software shouldn't crash on invalid user input. That said, the causes could be anything from bug in VS itself, to bug in some third-party extension you're using, to system problems.

Make sure you have all the latest OS updates and service packs for VS2005. If it still repros then, report it as a bug to [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback), and people responsible for this product area will take it from there.

Comment: It's not that I don't agree with you, it's just that it's Microsoft, it is supposed to crash under mysterious circumstances and not due to a bug:P 
Anyway, yes, I have all the updates and from what I found "Googling" around there seems to be a bug indeed.Still is there no way to add a .settings file some other way?

Comment: You can try to manually edit the `.csproj` file in any text editor and see if it works then. Oh, and check my profile ;)

Comment: Check my last edit... I'm starting to believe that MS programming is more about magic and less about programming (maybe I should change my major from applied math to applied sorcery or something :P)

Comment: Oh, I missed the "C++" part of the question. Well, I can tell you that this (C++/CLI & WinForms) isn't a very well supported scenario in any case - you should really stick to C#/VB for that sort of thing.

Comment: Well now it's too late to change, also I'm supposed to use C++ for this program, so I can't change it now... Still though any work around?

Comment: None that I know of. I'd still recommend you to go through the bug reporting process (in addition to asking it here and elsewhere on forums etc) - the team responsible for the component might be in the best position to figure out the workaround, if there's any.